# PHP function parse_str returns unexpected array

Tags: php, arrays

```
$string = "Title[]=Trekking&Title[]=Climbing&Title[]=Expeditions";
parse_str($string, $output);
print_r ($output);
```

The printed array is unexpected:

```
Array (
        [Title] => Array (
            [0] => Trekking [1] => Climbing [2] => Expeditions
        )
)
```

I'm not sure what happened. Here's my desired output:

```
Array (
  ['Title'] => "Trekking",
  ['Title'] => "Climbing",
  ['Title'] => "Expeditions"
)
```

Later, I want to print my array with:

```
for ($i=0; $i<count($output); $i++){
  echo $output['Title'][$i]."<br />";
}
```

Comment: So, what you have in you `But, I need:` section is not possible. You cannot have multiple items in an array with the same key like that. However, your `for later` bit should work if you change `count($output)` to `count($output['Title'])` I think.

Comment: @JonStirling thanks for your help. The donkey is me. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`parse_str` is working normally. Your expected output is impossible; arrays permit only unique keys. If you want to print titles without modifying your array, you need only change `count($output)` to `count($output['Title'])`; it will iterate over all of the titles in the `$output['Title']` array and print them. You are only seeing the first item in your original loop because `count($output)` is 1 rather than 3.

However, if you're looking for an array of arrays, each with its own `'Title'` key as in your desired output block, e.g. `$output[$i]['Title']`, you can do this with the following:

```
$string = "Title[]=Trekking&Title[]=Climbing&Title[]=Expeditions";
parse_str($string, $output);

$output = array_map(function ($e) {
    return ["Title" => $e];
}, $output["Title"]);

print_r ($output);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Title] => Trekking
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Title] => Climbing
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Title] => Expeditions
        )

)
```